# How do I get rid of #<User:0x1095e07b8> after calling User.each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

After looping through a User model in rails and displaying some columns, at the end of the view I get:

```
  #<User:0x1095e07b8>#<User:0x1095dfed0>#<User:0x1095de080>
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of this? Also what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using this for your loop:

```
<%= User.all.each do |user| %>
```

The equals sign will print the output of that function to the page. Drop the equals to omit the output:

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
```

The looping will still occur, but the output won't hit the view.